# Convert a varchar timestamp field to an actual date field

Tags: mysql

I inherited a really messy, poorly-designed database, and there are certain things I can't change.  The timestamp field in the database is a varchar field, which contains data that looks like this:
1595974379
1595977031
1596033136
It's not even a proper date format.

When I output the data on screen, I can tweak it through code to display the actual date:
`$transdate = date("Y.m.d",$getLedger->getColumnVal("timestamp"));`

However, is there a way to convert ALL of the dates in the database to an actual date instead of having to deal with a date being a varchar field?  Is there a way to do this without losing all of the data?  I created a new field, called transdate, which IS a date field.

I tried updating that field with data from the timestamp (varchar) field, but it's not working.

```
UPDATE transactions SET transdate = STR_TO_DATE(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I get an error message that says: Incorrect datetime value: '1595974379' for function str_to_date

I would like to take the data from the timestamp field, convert it to an actual date, and move that date into the transdate field.

Thank you!

Comment: The function you want is `FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)`

Comment: So it would be  UPDATE transactions SET transdate = FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp,'%Y.%m.%d')

Comment: No. Have you looked at the documentation. Why would `FROM_UNIXTIME()` need a format string. The argument is a numeric timestamp, the result is a `DATETIME`. There's no formatting.

Comment: Or read the linked question.

Comment: `SET transdate = FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)`

Comment: Barmar, thank you!  It worked but I can't select your comment as the answer...

Comment: I didn't post an answer that can be accepted, since it's already answered in the duplicate question.

Comment: Barmar, thank you for your help.  I didn't see the previous post, obviously.  I appreciate your help!